# RAW RSA signature verification with crypto++ library

Tags: c++, cryptography, rsa, crypto++

How it is possible to verify a digital signature with the crypto++ library?

The input data is:

- public_key BASE64 encoded hex string.
- public exponent from the public key.
- signature as hex string.

I don't know the private key part.

I have written this test function but it alway ends with "VerifierFilter: digital signature not valid" error.

The key here is exported from a valid KeyPair!

```
void rawRSAVerificationTest()
{

// RSA 2048 digital signature verification
try {

    std::string pupKeyStr ("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");
    //sha256 hashed data signature
    std::string signatureStr = "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";

    //Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT)
    std::string pupExpStr ("0x10001");

    CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool rng;
    CryptoPP::RSA::PublicKey pubKeyRaw;

    CryptoPP::Integer pup_key_cast( static_cast<CryptoPP::Integer> (pupKeyStr.c_str()));
    CryptoPP::Integer pup_exp_cast( static_cast<CryptoPP::Integer> (pupExpStr.c_str()));

    pubKeyRaw.Initialize(pup_key_cast, pup_exp_cast);
    if (!pubKeyRaw.Validate(rng, 3))
    {   
        std::cout << "Error while public key validation" << std::endl;
    }

    CryptoPP::RSASS<CryptoPP::PSS,  CryptoPP::SHA256>::Verifier verifier_sha256(pubKeyRaw);


    CryptoPP::StringSource( signatureStr, true,   
        new CryptoPP::SignatureVerificationFilter(   
        verifier_sha256, NULL,   
        CryptoPP::SignatureVerificationFilter::THROW_EXCEPTION   
        ) // SignatureVerificationFilter   
        ); // StringSource   

}
catch( CryptoPP::Exception& e )
{
    std::cerr << "ERROR: " << e.what() << std::endl;
}
catch( ... )
{
    std::cerr << "ERROR: Unknown verify signature error" << std::endl;
}
}
```

What i have missed?

I will be very grateful for any help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "raw"? Which RSA signature scheme was used to create the signature? PSS?

Comment: That looks more like a hexadecimal encoded modulus to me. It's exactly 512 characters in size (which means 256 bytes or 2048 bits). What do the "cast" statements do?

Comment: I mean with RAW RSA: Performing encryption and decryption operations using Crypto++'s with RSA primitives.

Comment: Yes it is a hexadecimal encoded modulus. The cast is used for the crypto++ Integer Class. Which imports a modulus string to this class.

Comment: Additional info is that "pupKeyStr" does not have the usual PKCS#1 container format, it's the plain key modulus!

Comment: Your signatureStr is 32 bytes long. The probability that this is actually a RSA signature with a 2048 bit RSA key is incredibly small. Most probably this is just the SHA-256 hash. Of course you need the hash to verify the signature, but you also need the actual signature. To verify an RSA signature, you need four pieces of data: the modulus, the public exponent, the hash (or the entire signtext, so you can calculate the hash) and the signature.

Comment: Thanks! Yes the signature is to short, i have now recalculated the signature with a padded sha256 hash over the data. The RSA signature size equal now the RSA keysize.

Comment: OK, so the signature size is now correct in the question, but did that solve your question or not?

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't solve this failure! Did i need a BER/DER encoding for the signature or the imported puplic key? Maby there is also a endian byte encoding needed to solve this issue?

Comment: Also see [RSA Cryptography](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Rsa_cryptography) and [Raw RSA](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Raw_RSA) on the Crypto++ wiki.

Answer (score 2):

> How it is possible to verify a digital signature with the crypto++ library?

Well, that one is easy when you know where to look. From the Crypto++ wiki on [RSA Signature Schemes](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/RSA_Signature_Schemes):

```
RSA::PrivateKey privateKey = ...;
RSA::PublicKey publicKey = ...; 

////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Setup
string message = "RSA-PSSR Test", signature, recovered;    

////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Sign and Encode
RSASS<PSSR, SHA1>::Signer signer(privateKey);

StringSource ss1(message, true, 
    new SignerFilter(rng, signer,
        new StringSink(signature),
        true // putMessage for recovery
   ) // SignerFilter
); // StringSource

////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Verify and Recover
RSASS<PSSR, SHA1>::Verifier verifier(publicKey);

StringSource ss2(signature, true,
    new SignatureVerificationFilter(
        verifier,
        new StringSink(recovered),
        THROW_EXCEPTION | PUT_MESSAGE
   ) // SignatureVerificationFilter
); // StringSource

cout << "Verified signature on message" << endl;
cout << "Message: " << recovered << endl;
```

---

```
CryptoPP::RSASS<CryptoPP::PSS,  CryptoPP::SHA256>::Verifier verifier_sha256(pubKeyRaw);
```

A few questions:

- Should that be `PSS` (signature scheme with appendix) or `PSSR` (signature scheme with recovery)?
- Are you certain its not, for example, PKCS1v15?
- If it is a recovery scheme, is the signature at the beginning or end of the hex encoded `signatureStr`?

---

This original `Integer` initialization was probably wrong. Crypto++ will attempt to parse the string as a decimal integer, and not a hexadecimal integer because in lacks a `0x` prefix and `h` suffix (one or the other should be present).

You should add the prefix, suffix, or use the byte array constructor. The byte array constructor is shown below.

```
std::string pupKeyStr ("e0c3851114c758fb...");

string pupKeyBin;
StringSource ss1(pupKeyStr, true,
    new HexDecoder(
        new StringSink(pupKeyBin)
    )
);

CryptoPP::Integer pup_key_cast( (unsigned char*)pupKeyBin.data(), pupKeyBin.size() );
```

---

```
StringSource( signatureStr, true, ...
...
```

This is probably wrong. You probably need something like:

```
string signatureBin;
StringSource ss1(signatureStr, true,
    new HexDecoder(
        new StringSink(signatureBin)
    )
);

StringSource ss2(signatureBin, true,
    new SignatureVerificationFilter(...
    ...
```

---

I tried the code with the binary signature using both `PSSA` and `PSSR`. Neither worked. I also tried with [SignatureVerificationFilter's `SIGNATURE_AT_BEGIN` and `SIGNATURE_AT_END`](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/SignatureVerificationFilter). Neither worked. And I tried the combinations with `SHA1` and `RSASSA_PKCS1v15_SHA_Verifier`. Nothing worked.

Can you verify precisely what you have?